# Form Validation error in Internet Explorer 7/8

Tags: javascript, forms, validation, internet-explorer

I am using the following javascript to check my form before post, but the check is not working in IE7 and IE8, this is the form code with the onClick (also onSubmit is not working).
In Internet Explorer it just skips the check and sends the details.

```
<form action="bedankt.php" method="post" onClick="return checkforblank();" /></form>
```

This is the javascript i am using:

```
function checkforblank() {

var errormessage = "";

    if (document.getElementById('voornaam').value == "") {
    errormessage += "u bent vergeten uw voornaam in te vullen, ";
    document.getElementById('voornaam').style.bordercolor = "red";
    }

    if (document.getElementById('achternaam').value == "") {
    errormessage += "u bent vergeten uw achternaam in te vullen, " ;
    document.getElementById('achternaam').style.bordercolor = "red";
    }

    if (document.getElementById('dag').value == "") {
    errormessage += "u bent vergeten een dag te selecteren, " ;
    document.getElementById('dag').style.bordercolor = "red";
    }

    if (document.getElementById('maand').value == "") {
    errormessage += "u bent vergeten een maand te selecteren, " ;
    document.getElementById('maand').style.bordercolor = "red";
    }

    if (document.getElementById('jaar').value == "") {
    errormessage += "u bent vergeten een jaar te selecteren, " ;
    document.getElementById('jaar').style.bordercolor = "red";
    }


var inputVal = document.getElementById('telefoonnummer').value;
if (inputVal == "") {
    errormessage += "u bent vergeten uw 10 cijferige telefoonnummer in te vullen ";

} else if (inputVal != "" && inputVal.length !== 10) {
    console.log("error");
    errormessage += "u bent vergeten uw 10 cijferige telefoonnummer in te vullen ";
    //set your error message here
} else {
    console.log("success");
}

if (errormessage != "") {
    console.log("error present");
    $(".error-messages").text(errormessage).fadeIn();
    return false;
}

else {
    document.getElementsByTagName("form")[0].submit();
}

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*1*. change all `console.log` to

```
window.console && console.log
```

since that only works in IE if the console is open

*2*. change

```
else {
    document.getElementsByTagName("form")[0].submit();
}
```

to

```
return true;
```

since you already are submitting the form and you do not need to have an else after the return false in the previous statement

I had a go at the whole thing since it bothered me to see all the repeating code
 - also you use jQuery, so I converted from DOM

Note I changed the class to ID for the error messages

[**Live Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/VbVux/)

```
function isValid(fldId,len) {
   var fld = $("#"+fldId);
   var val = fld.val();
    window.console && console.log(fld,fldId)
   if (val == "" || (len && val.length<len)) {
      fld.css("borderColor","red");
      return false;
   }      
   fld.css("borderColor","black");
   return true;
}

$(function() {
  $("form").on("submit",function() {
    var errormessage = [];

    if (!isValid('voornaam')) {
      errormessage.push("u bent vergeten uw voornaam in te vullen, ");
    }
    if (!isValid('achternaam')) {
      errormessage.push("u bent vergeten uw achternaam in te vullen, ");
    }
    if (!isValid('dag')) {
      errormessage.push("u bent vergeten een dag te selecteren, ");
    }
    if (!isValid('maand')) {
      errormessage.push("u bent vergeten een maand te selecteren, ");
    }
    if (!isValid('jaar')) {
      errormessage.push("u bent vergeten een jaar te selecteren, ");
    }
    if (!isValid('telefoonnummer',10)) {
      errormessage.push("u bent vergeten uw 10 cijferige telefoonnummer in te vullen");
    } 
    if (errormessage.length>0) {
      window.console && console.log("error present");
      $("#error-messages").html(errormessage.join('<br/>')).fadeIn();
      return false;
    }
    window.console && console.log("success");
    return true;
  });
});
```

Comment: ga ik nog even naar kijken, maar het eerste deed het hem al :)

Comment: Trust me, you do not want to submit a form in the submit event.

Comment: I get an error somewhere on the third sentence:
if (fld.value == "" || (len && fld.value.length<len) {

Comment: Done. Also did you a fiddle